# How to set up permissions on foreign table using postgres_fdw?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

The source data is in a *keys* table in the *public* schema of  database *keys*  (reference pg docs:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) :

```
create table keys (
    id varchar not null,
    keyname varchar not null,
    created timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
    modified timestamp default current_timestamp not null
);
```

The referencing user/schema/database is *vids*/*public*/*vids* .

1. Set up the server connection

```
CREATE SERVER keys
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host '1.2.3.4', port '5432', dbname 'keys');
```

2. Create the user mapping

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR vids
        SERVER keys
        OPTIONS (user 'keys', password 'keys');
```

3. Create the table mapping

```
create foreign table keys (
    id varchar not null,
    keyname varchar not null,
    created timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
    modified timestamp default current_timestamp not null
) server keys options (schema_name 'public', table_name 'keys');
```

4. Try to access the foreign table when connected as *vids* in the *vids* db:

```
vids=> select * from keys;
ERROR:  permission denied for foreign table keys
```

I do not understand given that the user *keys* is the owner of the *keys* table in the foreign database. What should be done here?

Comment: What is "referencing user"?

Comment: @jjanes  I clarified in the question as such:  user/schema/database is _vids_/_public_/_vids_

Comment: It still isn't clear which user is logged into which database on which server at each step of this procedure.  Also, you created a user mapping for `clip`, which not a user you appear to use anywhere else.

Comment: The error message suggest the problem is on the local side.  The local representation of the foreign table is not owned by `vids`, and `vids` does not have permissions to it.  So it never gets far enough to figure out if `keys` has access to `keys` on the foreign side.

Comment: @jjanes  thx i will check the perms on that local representation.    the `clip` was a typo it was corrected to `vids`.

Comment: @jjanes Yes grantint `all` on the `foreign table` to the local `user mapping`  fixed the permissions problem. connectivity is still not working but that's on me. Feel free [/encouraged] to make an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment by @jjanes:

> the error message suggest the problem is on the local side". The local repfresentation of the foreign table is nowned by `vids` and `vids` does not have permissions to it. So it never gets far enough to figure out if `keys` has access to `keys` on the foreign side

So the correction to my steps was:

```
 grant all on table keys to clips;
```